# table overlap to next chart when allow autofit in aspose.word in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I have a table named `table`  and then i put a chart in my .docx file .but when I set

`table.AllowAutoFit = true;`

and

`table.AutoFit(AutoFitBehavior.FixedColumnWidths);`

table overlap to next char.

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please share your input Word document here for testing. I will investigate the issue and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by noob solution:
after table I put a loop of new line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      {
          builder.InsertParagraph();
          builder.Writeln();
      }
```

I know above code is noob solution but it is only solution for solve this problem.(without using pagebreak)